# iOS NSURLConnection with SSL: Accepting an expired self-signed certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate, security-framework

I have a shipped app that uses the following code to secure an SSL connection using a self-signed certificate that is shipped with the app.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge %@ FAILURES=%d", [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod], (int)[challenge previousFailureCount]);

    /* Setup */
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace   = [challenge protectionSpace];
    assert(protectionSpace);
    SecTrustRef trust                       = [protectionSpace serverTrust];
    assert(trust);
    CFRetain(trust);  // Make sure this thing stays around until we're done with it
    NSURLCredential *credential             = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];

    /* Build up the trust anchor using our root cert */

    int err;
    SecTrustResultType trustResult = 0;
    err = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(trust, certs);
    if (err == noErr) {
        err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust,&trustResult);
    }
    CFRelease(trust);  // OK, now we're done with it

    // http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1360/_index.html
    BOOL trusted = (err == noErr) && ((trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed) || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultConfirm) || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified));

    // Return based on whether we decided to trust or not
    if (trusted) {
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Trust evaluation failed for service root certificate");
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I made a huge oversight. SSL certificates expire. So when the expiry date passes I'm assuming the app is going to stop working properly! There's nothing I can do for the current version of the app - that's going to stop working soon.

I need to release an update and in order to avoid this in the future I would like to allow the self-signed certificate even if it has expired.

How do I modify my code above to trust the certificate even if it has expired?

Comment: Is is good enough to simply accept `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure` as another acceptable trust result?

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:Nil];
...
...
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
  if([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]){
    if([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:@"mydomain.com"]){
      NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
      completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
  }
}
```